# what is the meaning of PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT in SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using ExpressCheckout and testing Paypal in the sandbox. I've noticed if I set a higher amount of `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT` in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment()` then in `SetExpressCheckout()` (e.g. $30 USD in `SetExpressChecout()`, $50 USD in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment()`), Paypal will transfer $50 USD to my sandbox business account from my sandbox personal account.

Is it because this is a sandbox server or something I should know ?

I am constructing a website which is required to charge an advance from the buyer and collect what remains of the net price a few days later. If this is a feature of Paypal Express Checkout, I will set the amount of advance in `SetExpressCheckout()` and the total Net Price in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment()`. Thereafter, the buyer will only see the advance amount in Paypal to decrease the confusion. If we said we only charge the advance, but in Paypal show the total amount of net price, it might cause confusion.

In my test it works in the sandbox, but Paypal will reply `SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED=true` in this situation. Paypal documentation explains "Flag to indicate whether you would like to redirect the buyer to sign up for PayPal after completing the transaction." What does that mean? 
Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: I would like to clarify my question is:
e.g.
SetExpressCheckout: $10 USD (when the buyer click checkout )
DoExpressCheckoutPayment: $30 USD ( when the buyer confirm the order in merchant web)
DoAuthorization:  $30 USD ( right after DoExpressCheckoutPayment)
DoCapture:   $10 USD (right after DoAuthorization)
DoCapture:   $20 USD ( maybe 1 week later )

Can I Set only $10 USD in SetExpressCheckout()? Paypal allows this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to go about doing this, as DoExpressCheckoutPayment needs to be completed within three hours of SetExpressCheckout being called (and having generated a TOKEN). What you'll want to use is PayPal [Authorization & Capture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_authcapture) (see also [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture)).

1. Call SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment with the total
   amount you wish to charge and ensure you pass
   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization in both.
2. Call [DoCapture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoCapture) and run a partial capture on the transaction. By running a partial capture, you leave the remainder open to be captured at a later date (`COMPLETETYPE=NotComplete`)
3. Once you're ready to capture the remainder, call DoCapture again and set `COMPLETETYPE=Complete`. After it a capture is completed, you cannot capture any more funds from that specific transaction ID, regardless of whether or not you captured the full amount or not.

Comment: Thank you. yes, what I am planning to use is to set PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Order, and I know it requires DoAuthorization and DoCapture. My question is, I've noticed I can SetExpressCheckout to the partial amount ( advance ) , and DoExpressCheckout to the Net Price amount. I need to confirm is it a Paypal feature? or because it is sandbox server?

Comment: That's because of the Sandbox environment. In a normal situation you can only run DoExpressCheckoutPayment up to the amount you initiated through SetExpressCheckout.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert "regardless of whether or not you finally". Finally what? Also, why can't the PayPal tutorials be as clear and concise as this?

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Once you call DoCapture with `COMPLETETYPE=Complete`, that authorization cannot be captured anymore, regardless of whether or not you captured the full amount.